# Force asset download instead of playing in browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm currently using Azure Media Services and I'm unable to force a video download instead of in-browser player when clicking the "download" link generated after creating a download locator.
I've got the video.js player working fine with a streaming locator but whatever I do, it seems that I can't force a browser to download the video (well, right click and save work fine but the end user probably won't expect this to download the video directly).
Is there a working example somewhere that shows how to force a client browser download ?

I tried adding download tag to the html element but that did not help.

```
<a href="https://<endpoint to download url>" download><i role="none" class="Icon Icon-download"></i></a>
```

FYI the content-type header of the response is

```
video/mp4
```

When you click on the element it sends the request to the backend service which generates a SAS and redirects the request for blob download.

Thank you

Comment: Is the endpoint a stream?

Comment: @aloisdg no, it is a api endpoint which redirects to download url for blob, I am trying to download a video file from azure storage blob container

Comment: Can you share the link to the file?

Comment: @aloisdg no
When you click on the element it sends the request to the backend service which generates a SAS and redirects the request for blob download. Because the blob has content-type video/mp4 when we receive the blob the browser plays it.